# Netbeans debug web service and web client

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans

I'm using Netbeans to create both a web client and a web service which are deployed on Glashfish (in debug mode).

I put some breakpoints in the web service but when I launch the web client (in debug) and trigger the call to the web service's methods, it never stops at the breakpoints I set.

I do get a proper SOAP response so I know the code of the web service is executed. 
Is there a way to debug the web service when launching the web client?

For now I use a Main class in the web service to simulate the client or for methods not using complex types, I can use 'Test web service' from Netbeans.

Answer (score 1):

Some thoughts:

- Get SOAP-UI for testing. Its much better than any client you can
  generate. You can also use it between services.

Once you have SOAP-UI installed launch glassfish in debug mode. Deploy your web-services. Create a new SOAP-UI project and point it to the WSDL file of the web services you deployed.

*WARNING: SOAP-UI aint pretty but it is pretty good.*

Once you have imported the WSDL open the SOAP project nodes till you see the operations of the web service.

You should see something like this:

[image: SOAP UI]

Expand the operations and fill in the missing pieces of the request. Missing values will be indicated by a ? in the XML request, they should look something like this in the initial request:

```
   <ecol:accountTotalDue>
           <!--Optional:-->
           <acc:AccountKeyInfo>
              <!--Optional:-->
              <acc:Client_Ref>?</acc:Client_Ref>
              <!--Optional:-->
              <acc:Debt_ID>?</acc:Debt_ID>
           </acc:AccountKeyInfo>
           <!--Optional:-->
           <acc:Total_Due>?</acc:Total_Due>
        </ecol:accountTotalDue>
```

You can hard code them like this:

```
    <ecol:accountTotalDue>
           <!--Optional:-->
           <acc:AccountKeyInfo>
              <!--Optional:-->
              <acc:Client_Ref>12834756183754</acc:Client_Ref>
              <!--Optional:-->
              <acc:Debt_ID>?</acc:Debt_ID>
           </acc:AccountKeyInfo>
           <!--Optional:-->
           <acc:Total_Due>10000000.00</acc:Total_Due>
        </ecol:accountTotalDue>
```

Note you can script them too for example my web services requires a GUUID and message date time in a special header sections so I do the following:

```
<irix:MsgReqHdr>
         <irix:MsgGUID>${=java.util.UUID.randomUUID()}</irix:MsgGUID>
           <!--Optional:-->
           <irix:MsgDateTime>${=javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(GregorianCalendar.getInstance())}</irix:MsgDateTime>
</irix:MsgReqHdr>
```

You could set up different requests to test different scenarios. It is really a must HAVE if you are doing serious Web services development. It also does REST.

This generally works a lot better for me than anything else. I have done this with JBoss, Glassfish, Karaf, Fuse and other servers so it will work.

Comment: Thanks for you input. It seems like a solid alternative! However, what I'm asking is in the context of a university lab and we are required to use NetBeans.

Comment: @JulioQc could you post some screenshots of how you start Glassfish? Also ask your lecturer if it is possible to use SOAP-ui as it is used in the industry much more than the test client thus much more relevant to your career.